# Select digits on the end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace only digits at the end of line with semicolon `;` using RegEx in Notepad++.

```
Before:
ddd 66 ffff 5
d 44 dds 55

After:
ddd 66 ffff;
d 44 dds;
```

I'm trying to find digits at the end of lines with expression

```
($)(\d+)
```

but Notepad++ can't find anything by use of this expression. How to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe ` *\d+ *(\n|$)`? I don't have notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

**Find:**

```
\s\d+$
```

**Replace:**

```
;
```

`\d+` will match one or more digits.  `$` will match the end of the line--this is non-capturing (so don't worry... the end of the line will not be replaced in a find/replace operation).  And so `\d+$` will match one or more digits immediately followed by the end of the line.

I included `\s` (a single whitespace character) because it looks like you want to replace the space preceding the digits as well.

Note that you will need to do "Replace All" for this to work like you want.  (because each regex match is for one instance only)

Comment: This approach won't scale if the regex becomes more complex and can't be bound by a single start/end anchor.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the regex were "more complex" and could not "be bound by a...anchor," then you would need a different regex without anchors entirely (and that would be a different question entirely). However, the OP specifically asked about a target match *defined* by "at the end of line."  Hence, why you need an anchor.

Comment: Your answer would replace a line which contains only a single space followed by a number, but we don't know if such a case should be a candidate for replacement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, my answer would replace any instance of `\s\d+$`, regardless of whether or not it is preceded by other characters on the line.  I do not use a start anchor like you do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen See this screenshot:  https://s23.postimg.org/yx9iaraez/Screen_Shot_2017_01_03_at_10_03_36_AM.png  You can also run the test yourself if you like.

Comment: @Travis regex101 has a `save regex` option that you can share.. It looks to me like both regexs would do the same thing. A space then any amount of numbers and the end of the line are replaced with a `;`.

Comment: @chris85 Good tip.  I hadn't realized that about regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this find/replace:

**find:**

```
^(.*) \d+$
```

**replace:**

```
\1;
```

The find regex above matches anything up to and excluding a final space followed by at least one digit.  If the end pattern for a given line is not space followed by one or more digits, the regex should not match.  The replacement is the capture group, what is in parenthesis, which is everything up to but excluding the final space and number.

Comment: This looks like it'd work, but it seems like overkill...  Why match everything on the line preceding the final few digits at all?  `^(.*)` is not necessary in order to correctly match `\d+$`